# While upgrading cluster autoscaler using Helm in Kubernetes, getting following error: rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks

I'm trying to upgrade cluster autoscaler using Helm in Kubernetes cluster on AWS EKS from v1.22.2 to v1.23.1 through Terraform. Helm chart version used is 9.24.0. I have already updated the default values file according to v1.23.1.

I get the following error: `rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists. Unable to continue with install: ServiceAccount "default" in namespace "cluster-autoscaler" exists and cannot be imported into the current release: invalid ownership metadata; label validation error: missing key "app.kubernetes.io/managed-by": must be set to "Helm"; annotation validation error: missing key "meta.helm.sh/release-name": must be set to "cluster-autoscaler"; annotation validation error: missing key "meta.helm.sh/release-namespace": must be set to "cluster-autoscaler"`

How to fix this? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set `rbac.serviceAccount.name` in values file to `"default"`. Changing it to `""` (leaving it empty) fixed the issue.

> `rbac.serviceAccount.name` is the name of the ServiceAccount to use. If not set and create is `true`, a name is generated using the fullname template.

Reference: [cluster autoscaler - helm chart - values file - rbac.serviceAccount.name](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/cluster-autoscaler-chart-9.24.0/charts/cluster-autoscaler/values.yaml#L289-L290)